# Need to supply 4 square waves (at 4 different frequencies-600,800,1000,1200 Hz) to 4 IR emitters at the same time using any microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, frequency, square

I need to design a circuit to supply 4 square waves at 50% duty cycle (at 4 different frequencies-600,800,1000,1200 Hz)  to 4 IR emitters respectively at the same time using any microcontroller.
Could someone help me with any circuit examples for that?
Also which microcontroller could I use for that?

Thank You!

Comment: At those low frequencies, pretty much any micro with at least 4 GPIO pins could do the job just by toggling the pins at appropriate delay times in an endless loop. But if you might even want the micro to do any more than than then you should look for one with 4 independent timer outputs to automate the job. "Shopping" for specific recommendations here is off-topic though.

Comment: Thank You So Much for your help! Any suggestions on which microcontroller would be best to use with 4 independent timer outputs? Also, where could I get the circuit to generate the square wave using the microcontroller? I am new to electrical engineering and so I am struggling with it a bit.

Comment: You don't need a "circuit to generate the square wave" - the microcontroller generates the square wave by toggling a pin up & down, and as I wrote above - shopping for recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: Okay, Thank You So Much! Also, if I am allowed to ask you this, would the micPIC18F452 microcontroller work? It does not have any Analog Output pin mentioned in its Datasheet.

Comment: A square wave is (usually) a digital signal - you don't need any analog outputs form the micro.

Answer (score 4):

You can either search for a microcontroller that has the appropriate hardware on-chip or, if you can stand a bit of jitter and have a fast micro, generate a periodic interrupt every 41.6666usec (using one timer and an appropriate clock such as 24MHz or 48MHz and timer configuration). At 24 or 48MHz you'd want an interrupt every 1000 or 2000 clock cycles respectively.

Then you would toggle the 1kHz pin every 500usec or 12 interrupts. The 1200Hz every 10 interrupts. The 800Hz every 15 interrupts and the 600Hz every 20 interrupts. The frequencies would be as accurate as the clock, but there would likely be a bit of jitter depending on how the Interrupt Service Routine (ISR) was written and the interrupt handling of the MCU.

Comment: Thank You So Much for your help! But can't I use a microcontroller with 4 different timer outputs and generate 4 square waves at 4 different frequencies? Any suggestions on which microcontroller would be helpful. I am new to electrical engineering and so I am struggling with it a bit.

Comment: Yes you can, but searching for it is your job. Eg, if it was an 8-bit MCU, one might pick Microchip for life cycle longevity and DIP availability in some particular situation. Then go to Microchip's website and find a selection guide that shows the number of timers and pick a suitable one from that range. Eg. PIC16F18xx. Or if you're more familiar with 32-bit ARM processors and have a toolchain up and running you might prefer a Cortex chip. Really depends on your situation and whether you're building 1 or 2, period, or trying to prototype a production design.

Comment: Note that the same basic math as I pointed out in the interrupt-based situation applies, so you should consider using an MCU clock that divides exactly like 3MHz, 6MHz, 12MHz, 24MHz, etc. to get exact nominal frequencies with a simple 8-bit MCU.